# Need help making site available externally

Tags: firewall, configuration, remote-access, cisco-asa, website

I'm trying to open a hole in the firewall (ASA 5505, v8.2) to allow external access to a Web application.  Via ASDM (6.3?), I've added the server as a Public Server, which creates a static NAT entry [I'm using the public IP that is assigned to 'dynamic NAT--outgoing' for the LAN, after confirming on the Cisco forums that it wouldn't bring everyone's access crashing down] and an incoming rule "any... public_ip... https... allow" but traffic is still not getting through.  When I look at the log viewer, it says it's denied by access-group outside_access_in, implicit rule, which is "any any ip deny"

I haven't had much experience with Cisco management.  I can't see what I'm missing to allow this connection through, and I'm wondering if there's anything else special I have to add.  I tried adding a rule (several variations) within that access-group to allow https to the server, but it never made a difference.  Maybe I haven't found the right combination? :P

I also made sure the Windows firewall is open on port 443, although I'm pretty sure the current problem is Cisco, because of the logs. :)

Any ideas?  If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks

Edit: 
First of all, I had this backward.  (Sorry)  Traffic is being blocked by access-group "inside_access_out" which is what confused me in the first place.  I guess I confused myself again in the midst of typing the question.

Here, I believe, is the pertinent information.  Please let me know what you see wrong.

```
access-list acl_in extended permit tcp any host PUBLIC_IP eq https  
access-list acl_in extended permit icmp CS_WAN_IPs 255.255.255.240 any  
access-list acl_in remark Allow Vendor connections to LAN  
access-list acl_in extended permit tcp host Vendor any object-group RemoteDesktop  
access-list acl_in remark NetworkScanner scan-to-email incoming (from smtp.mail.microsoftonline.com to PCs)  
access-list acl_in extended permit object-group TCPUDP any object-group Scan-to-email host NetworkScanner object-group Scan-to-email  
access-list acl_out extended permit icmp any any  
access-list acl_out extended permit tcp any any  
access-list acl_out extended permit udp any any  
access-list SSLVPNSplitTunnel standard permit LAN_Subnet 255.255.255.0  
access-list nonat extended permit ip VPN_Subnet 255.255.255.0 LAN_Subnet 255.255.255.0  
access-list nonat extended permit ip LAN_Subnet 255.255.255.0 VPN_Subnet 255.255.255.0  
access-list inside_access_out remark NetworkScanner Scan-to-email outgoing (from scanner to Internet)  
access-list inside_access_out extended permit object-group TCPUDP host NetworkScanner object-group Scan-to-email any object-group Scan-to-email  
access-list inside_access_out extended permit tcp any interface outside eq https

static (inside,outside) PUBLIC_IP LOCAL_IP[server object] netmask 255.255.255.255

access-group inside_access_out out interface inside  
access-group acl_in in interface outside
access-group acl_out out interface outside
```

I wasn't sure if I needed to reverse that "static" entry, since I got my question mixed up... and also with that last access-list entry, I tried interface inside and outside - neither proved successful... and I wasn't sure about whether it should be www, since the site is running on https.  I assumed it should only be https.

Comment: Could you post a "sanitized" config file with IP addresses using internal space and passwords blanked out?

Comment: The inbound ACL on the outside interface is missing a rule to allow the traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh yearh probably it's CISCO fault. Honestly for me ASDM it's a bit confusing so I will pass you the command lines directive:

```
ssh pix@INTERNAL_IP
[type cisco password]
enable
[retype password]
show conf <- retrieve the config plain text
```

Now you should have lines like that

```
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any interface outside eq www
```

Maybe the access-list name is different, but doesn't matter. Also in my case the outside interface it's an alias for the VLan2 on which is the internet connected. This allows traffic for www connection to be accepted.

Now for the port forwarding you need a line like that:

```
static (inside,outside) tcp interface www LOCAL_IP www netmask 255.255.255.255
```

Again the inside it's an name for my local interface, which act as an gateway for the network. If you con't have lines like that just add them with `configure terminal`. Add the magic lines and should work. If you need any help in the console just use the magic `?`:)

Comment: I'm sorry, I got my question backwards (apparently, inside_access_out is blocked).  I've posted an update, as I was unable to convert your answer to my scenario. :P

Comment: I was told on the Cisco forums to remove the inside_access_out group.  I was nervous about doing that (not sure about any other ramifications), so I resolved this by adding 'any any https allow' on that access group.  There is probably a better way of doing this, but I tried all combinations I could think of (server_ip as source, destination, etc... even if it didn't necessarily make sense - thought I might get lucky :P) with no success.  With the 'any any' it's working.  Thanks for the help!